# Navigating from an embedded to un-embedded ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have two `UIViewController` `A` and `B`.

`ViewController A` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` hence automatically inheriting a `UINavigationBar`.

While segueing from `ViewController B` which is not embedded to `A` the `UINavigationBar` disappears.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can i segue to `A` without embedding `B` to the `UINavigationController`?

Comment: you can add navigation bar manually from controllers tray

Comment: Then i would have to add manual bars for every ViewController embedded to that specific navigation controller. In a case where i have many viewControllers embedded it can be tedious. Is there another way...

Comment: you might be messing navigationBar in controller B. Better put `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)` in Controller A's `viewWillAppear` and check if it returns back.

Comment: You'd have to use a modal segue, and you should wire that segue to the NavigationController and not to A.

Comment: Does not work @Kamran